# How to remove the chapter number while still having the chapter name at the top of the page?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

Currently I have this:
[image]

I want to remove the chapter number, which i can easily do with `\chapter*{Acknowledgments}`.

This, however, makes the top line on all subsequent pages say the chapter name of the *previous*, unstarred, chapter.

How can I fix this?

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, titlepage]{report}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1: The name that I do not want}
\chapter*{Chapter 2: The name that I want}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2: The name that I want}

TEXT

\newpage

TEXT

\newpage

TEXT

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a small *compilable* code which reproduces your problem?

Comment: If I understand well, you do not want the chapter number to appear in the chapter heading. However, if this chapter has sections, should the chapter number appear as a prefix to the section number in the section heading?

Comment: No the number should not appear, but I would like the correct chapter name to appear. In the above example, I want Chapter 2 to appear at the top of the last page, but Chapter 1 is instead the one that appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposition, based on `titlesec` and `titleps`, which consists in making a group with a specific `\titleformat{\chapter}`, without the chapter number in the code. Note that the chapter numbers will all appear in the table of contents, unless you play with the `titletoc` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, titlepage]{report}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\huge\bfseries\filright}{\chaptername~\thechapter}{2.5ex}{}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\bfseries\filright}{\arabic{section}.}{0.3em}{}

\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\headrule
\sethead[\chaptertitle][][\thepage]{\thepage}{}{\sectiontitle}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}\counterwithin*{section}{chapter}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1: The name that I do not want}
\lipsum

{\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\huge\bfseries\filright}{}{0ex}{}

\chapter{Chapter 2: The name that I want}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\section{A First Section}
TEXT
\lipsum
\newpage
\section{Another Section}

TEXT

\newpage

TEXT

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What you see in the above image is not the real chapter number. You see it only because the code you posted has a chapter title   beginning with `Chapter 2:`.

Comment: Sorry yeah I was being silly, this is perfect thanks very much!

Comment: Please the chapter still has a number, but it is not displayed.

Comment: Ah wait how do I remove the number from the table of contents?

Comment: I think it can be done with `titletoc`. However, it's not so simple if you want to remove the number for only *some* chapters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly, after your `\tableofcontents` and before `TEXT` change your code to:

```
\chapter{Chapter 1: The name I do not want}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}          % only Parts numbered
\chapter{Chapter 2: The name I want}  % this will be put in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}           % subsections and above will be numbered
```